# How to think about risk vs. cost of information

Tags: terminology, game-theory

New poster so please help redirect me if this question isn't a good fit.

An important feature of a game I'm building is information.  This includes  data such as the opponent's location and everything a player can learn about breaking an opponent's code (breaking the code will give the player much more information, obviously).

The trick is, in seeking out the opponent's information some of the player's own information must be risked.   An example: a player can use a certain in-game tool to try and learn their opponent's position.  The attempt  will tell the opponent a little but about the player's location (narrowing it down to around a third of the play area), but if it is successful, the player will learn the opponent's precise location.

My question is, is there a name for this risk vs. benefit aspect of game development with regard to information attained?  I'd like to read up on the theory but can't figure out where to start.

EDIT - More information was requested, so here is an example.  Let's say there is a 32x32 grid available to players,so roughly 1000 possible locations.  Player 1 is at 10, 25.  Player 1 would like to find Player 2.  Player 1 uses a tool.  Here's how it works:

> Player 2 will get a positive result if Player 2 is within a radius of 10 units from their location, and a negative if not.  For a positive result, Player 1 will learn Player 2's exact location; for a negative result they will learn nothing.
> Player 2, regardless of their proximity to Player 1,will learn a little bit about Player 1's location.  Player 2 will learn which quarter of the play area contains Player 1.  In this case, 10,25 tells Player 2 that their opponent is in the "northeast" quadrant.

Comment: I don't know a specific branch of game theory related to your exact scenario. If you edit your question to provide more details though, we might be able to suggest useful game theoretic models/techniques to apply. Right now, knowing so little about your game, it's hard to know how we could quantify the value of information vs the risk of exposure. It sounds like some Shannon information theory could come into play in terms of quantifying uncertainty in bits, but to do that we's need to know how much tighter "precise" is and how hard that info is to obtain by other means.

Comment: What other ways of getting information are there? To be able to quantify how much time we've saved ourselves versus how much we risk saving our opponent, we need information about the game outside of this tool alone. Are there any costs or limitations to using this tool, like a number of charges, cooldown timer, or a resource investment, beyond just the risk of information leak?

Comment: When you say information, you mean data. Information is a concept from signal processing, a measure of the lack of predictability of the data (messages) in a signal.

Comment: That concept of information is also applicable here. We consider the opponent's position as initially completely unknown and unpredictable, and each experiment reduces our uncertainty/increases predictability.